# React Router 4 for sub folder is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
   <switch>
     <Route exact path='/' component={main} />
     <Route path='/build/signup' component={SignUp} />
   </switch>
</Router>
```

The app resides in the localhost/build url. The homepage property in package.json is set as "localhost/build".

This is how the link to the SignUp component is implemented.

```
 <Router>
   <NavLink className='sign-up' to='/build/signup'>Register</NavLink>
 </Router>
```

Whenever I click on the sign-up link. localhost/build/signup is added to the url bar, but the SignUp component is not rendered.

Comment: You may need to import Switch from react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom` wrap your component that performs route change in it and it should work. for example

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom`

class NavComponent extends React.Component {
 render(){
   return (
       <Router>
         <NavLink className='sign-up' to='/build/signup'>Register</NavLink>
      </Router>
    )
 }
}
export default withRouter(NavComponent);
```